# Avoid double keystrokes for a given set of keys on OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard, software-recommendation

I am looking for a program for OS X that can prevent the user from inputting the same key twice in less than X milliseconds. The set of keys for which this limitation applies to should be configurable.

Any price and license is fine.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Software recommendations are off-topic for Ask Different.  You can ask this on the [SR](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site, instead.

Comment: @fbara Shopping or buying recommendations <> software recommendation. Also there is over a thousand questions in the software recommendation tags.

Comment: I'm going by this: "Basic Customer Support or **questions asking to recommend or find off-site resources (Mac/book/software/tutorial) are off-topic for Ask Different** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, edit to clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it.".  To me, this means this question should be asked on the SR site.  Further discussion is ongoing in the [Meta site](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/2870/88313).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Have you found anything? I'm interested in the same!

Comment: @adamsfamily Nothing yet.

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/aahung/Unshaky

Comment: @adamsfamily nice, thanks for sharing, you are welcome to post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found **Unshaky** on GitHub (https://github.com/aahung/Unshaky)

I've been testing it for about day and so far it has been working fabulously! During a full workday I experienced a double-keystroke only once.

Please note that you have to set it up:

[image]

I put 40ms delay for each key:

[image]

I also made an exception for the Tab and Delete keys which I regularly hit repeatedly:

[image]

I am not affiliated with Unshaky in any way.